# Nuxt3 + Pinia + VueUse -> useStorage() not working

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, pinia, vueuse

**Setup:** I'm using Nuxt3 + Pinia + VueUse.

**Goal:**
I want to save a state of a pinia store to localstorage via VueUse: `useStorage`.

**Problem:**
For some reason no item is created in localstorage. I feel like I'm missing something here. In components I can use `useStorage` fine.

in **stores/piniaStoreVueUse.js**

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { useStorage } from '@vueuse/core'

export const usePiniaStoreVueUse = defineStore('piniaStoreUseVue', {
    state: () => {
        return { 
            state: useStorage('my-state', 'empty'),
        }
    },
    actions: {
        enrollState() {
            this.state = 'enroll';
        },
        emptyState() {
            this.state = 'empty'; 
        },
    },
    getters: {
    }
});
```

in **components/SampleComponentStatePiniaVueUse.vue**

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
    import { usePiniaStoreVueUse } from '~/stores/piniaStoreVueUse';

    const piniaStoreVueUse = usePiniaStoreVueUse();
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        piniaStoreVueUse.state: {{ piniaStoreVueUse.state }}<br>
        <button class="button" @click="piniaStoreVueUse.enrollState()">
            enrollState
        </button>
        <button class="button" @click="piniaStoreVueUse.emptyState()">
            clearState
        </button>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

**[Live Version here](https://intrinsify-mvp-intrinsify-dev.vercel.app/state)**

Thank you.

Comment: I do have a succesful `piniaStoreState: "empty"` in my localStorage. Isn't it what's expected here? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Ah I JUST found a fix and put it live. I'll add it as an answer here in a minute

Answer (score 10):

I found a solution to this problem and it seems to work pretty well. I have not done extensive testing but it seems to work.

After loads of digging I came across a page in the Pinia documentation: [Dealing with Composables](https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/composables.html#ssr)

NOTES:

```
npm i -D @vueuse/nuxt @vueuse/core
```

My Tested Code:

```js
//storageTestStore.js

import { defineStore, skipHydrate } from "pinia";
import { useLocalStorage } from '@vueuse/core'

export const useStorageTestStore = defineStore('storageTest', {
    state: () => ({
      user: useLocalStorage('pinia/auth/login', 'bob'),
    }),
    actions: {
        setUser(user) {
            this.user = user
        }
    },
  
    hydrate(state, initialState) {
      // in this case we can completely ignore the initial state since we
      // want to read the value from the browser
      state.user = useLocalStorage('pinia/auth/login', 'bob')
    },
  })
```

`test.vue (~~/pages/test.vue)`

```html
<script setup>
    import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
    import { useStorageTestStore } from "~~/stores/storageTestStore";

    const storageTestStore = useStorageTestStore();

    // create array with 10 random first names
    const firstNames = [
        "James",
        "John",
        "Robert",
        "Michael",
        "William",
        "David",
        "Richard",
        "Charles",
        "Joseph",
        "Thomas",
    ];

    const updateUser = () => {
        storageTestStore.setUser(
            firstNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstNames.length)]
        );
    };
</script>

<template>
    <div class="max-w-[1152px] mx-auto">
        <h1 class="text-xl">{{ storageTestStore.user }}</h1>
        <button
            class="text-lg bg-emerald-300 text-emerald-900 p-5 rounded-lg"
            @click="updateUser()"
        >
            Change User
        </button>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped></style>
```

The state fully persisted after browser reloads and navigating in the application.

Answer (score 8):

### I found an answer to this:

Nuxt3 uses SSR by default. But since useStorage() (from VueUse) uses the browsers localstorage this can’t work.

**Solution 1:**

Disables SSR in your `nuxt.config.js`

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: false,
  
  // ... other options
})
```

**Careful:** 
This globally disables SSR.

**Solution 2:**

Wrap your component in <client-only placeholder="Loading…”>

```
 <client-only placeholder="Loading...">
    <MyComponent class="component-block"/>
 </client-only>
```

I'd love to hear about other ways to deal with this. I feel like there should be a better way.

Comment: You could also do a quick check like `if (process.client) {` to apply only a specific method to run on the frontend. Otherwise, some lifecycle hooks are [called only on the client-side](https://nuxtjs.org/pt/docs/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle#nuxt-lifecycle) too.

Answer (score 5):

I'm folowed this topic two week. My resoleved use plugin [pinia-plugin-persistedstate.](https://github.com/prazdevs/pinia-plugin-persistedstate) I'm touch plugin/persistedstate.js and add `persist: true`, in Pinia `defineStore()`

First install plugin `yarn add pinia-plugin-persistedstate` or `npm i pinia-plugin-persistedstate`

```
#plugin/persistedstate.js
import { createNuxtPersistedState } from 'pinia-plugin-persistedstate'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
 nuxtApp.$pinia.use(createNuxtPersistedState(useCookie))
})
```

and

```
#story.js
export const useMainStore = defineStore('mainStore', {
state: () => {
    return {
        todos: useStorage('todos', []),
        ...
    }
},
persist: true, #add this
getters: {...},
actions: {...}
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I found also official documentation: https://github.com/prazdevs/pinia-plugin-persistedstate/blob/main/docs/frameworks/nuxt-3.md

Comment: Yeap! This documentation created 14 days ago. But we get this trouble in about 3 mounth ago. Thank you for link!

Answer (score -2):

you can use ref with useStorage()

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { useStorage } from '@vueuse/core'

export const usePiniaStoreVueUse = defineStore('piniaStoreUseVue', {
    state: () => {
        return { 
            state: ref(useStorage('my-state', 'empty')),
        }
    },
    actions: {
        enrollState() {
            this.state = 'enroll';
        },
        emptyState() {
            this.state = 'empty'; 
        },
    },
    getters: {
    }
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For some reason this doens't create a localStorage item, but it does work and the state is persistant. Thank you.